# Gradle multiple sourcsets only main is included in jar

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle project with two sourcesets main and api.
But when i execute `gradle build` only the source of main is included
I'm using the following code:

```
sourceSets {
api {
    java {
        runtimeClasspath += main.output
        compileClasspath += main.output
    }
}
```

To add the sourcesets.
Hopefully you can help me that gradle also includes the api sourceset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all additional source sets, you have to add appropriate entries in `dependencies` and `jar`. If you have a source set named 'api':

```
sourceSets {
    api{
    }
}

dependencies {
    //depend on the source set
    compile sourceSets.api.output
}

jar{
    //include output of API source set
    from  sourceSets.api.output
}
```